# Probability of a sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

For all $k = 1, 2, ...$, consider $f_k: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \{1, 2, ..., C\}$, for some given positive integer $C$, with the following properties.

- For all $k$, if $(y_1, ..., y_k)$ is a permutation of $(x_1, ..., x_k)$, then $ f_k( (y_1, ..., y_k) ) = f_k( (x_1, ..., x_k) ) $.
- For all $k$, and all $x, y_1, y_2, ... \in \mathbb{R}$, $f_k( (x, x, y_1, y_2,...) ) = f_{k-1}( x, y_1, y_2, ...)$.

Let $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P} \right)$ be a probability space.

For a given positive integer $N$, define $c := \text{ess} \sup_{ X \in \mathbb{R}^N } f_N( X )$, where the $X$ is a set of $N$ random i.i.d. variables extracted from $\mathbb{P}$.

Now the main point. Consider a sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, with $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$, and such that the $x_i$'s are i.i.d. extractions from $\mathbb{P}$.

Consider the sequence

$$ f_1( x_1 ), \ \ldots, \ f_k( (x_1, ..., x_k) ), \ \ldots.$$

At some point, we will have $f_K((x_1, ..., x_K)) \geq c$ with high probability.

Question. Is it possible to upper bound $\mathbb{P}^k\left( \{ (x_1, ..., x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k \mid f_k( x_1, ..., x_k ) > c \}\right) $ by an explicit function of $k$, which goes to $0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$?

If not, what kind of similar statements can be derived?

Comment. Possibly, I would like to use some variation of [Hoeffding's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) or [Chebyshev's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).

Comment: What does this mean? *$c := \sup_{ X \in \mathbb{R}^N } f_N( X )$, where the $X$ is a set of $N$ random i.i.d. variables extracted from $\mathbb{P}$.* If you take $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n}$ then you don't have to specify what $x$ is. Currently, you seem to have two contradictory definition of the optimization domain

Comment: It loosely means that $c := \sup_{ \omega \in \Omega } f_N( ( x_1(\omega), ..., x_N(\omega) ) ) $. Namely, $c$ is the supremum of $f_N(X)$ where $X$ is a collection of extractions from $\mathbb{P}$, and $\Omega$ is the sample space. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Let's put it this way: how does it differ from $\sup_{y\in \mathbb R^n}f_n(y)$? Also, $\max$ is enough here as you're always maximizing over a subset of a finite co-domain of $f_n$.

Comment: I think it may differ. Suppose that $f_n$ is always $1$, unless $y = 0_n$ where $f_n( 0_n ) = 2$. Now if $\mathbb{P}( \{0\} ) = 0$ - i.e. the probability of extracting $x_i=0$ is null, then $c = 1$. On the other hand, $\max_{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n } f_n(y) = 2$.

Comment: What I mean, is that the point-wise structure of the map $x_i:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ is not uniquely determined by its distribution, so that there still may exist an $\omega\in \Omega$ such that $x_i(\omega) = 0$ but $\Bbb P(\{\omega\}) = 0$. Currently, as you're leaving free this structure, it is equivalent to say that the supremum is defined over all $\Bbb R^n$. You may want instead define
$$
  c_N := \inf\{m \in [0;C]: \Bbb P^N(f_N(x_1,\dots,x_N))> m = 0\}
$$
to be the *essential* supremum. Also, does $c$ depends on $k$ in the last probability in OP?

Comment: I know, I should invoke the essential supremum.

Comment: No, $c$ does not depend on $k$.

Comment: Why do we have $f_k\geq c$ with a high probability? Imagine that $f_1$ reaches $C$ and $N = 1$, but all other $f_k$ are bounded by $C-1$. As an alternative extreme, let all $f_k$ for $k > N$ be constant functions equal $c+1$, then the limit of the probability is $1$ and it is not possible to bound it with a function that converges to $0$.

Comment: "At some point, we will have fK((x1,...,xK))≥c with high probability." Sorry but there seems to be no reason why we should have that. // "Is it possible to upper bound..." No, unless you specify the functions $f_k$ (as it is, the context of the question is much too vague to say anything of value).

Comment: Because at some point one will explore all the sample space and get $f_K = c$.

Comment: To summarize: in Hoeffding's case you have a clearly converging behavior which you would like to bound. In your case the convergence by no means is presented. Also, you "at some moment ... with high probability" contradicts the will to find a converging bound.

Comment: If you would like to explore the whole sample space, you need the dependence between functions $f_k$. What is this dependence I don't know. I gave you some examples that show if you don't have dependence, then there no even intuition behind what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your examples. For instance, seems to me that $f_k = c+1$ for all $k > N$ happens with probability zero.

Comment: I probably see your point on the "dependence" of the $f_k$'s. Let me reformulate the problem accordingly.

Comment: I have now modified the question introduce some dependence on the $f_k$'s.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.